Mathematical questions about equivalence of actions (1d Liouville and Schwarzian)
https://arxiv.org/abs/1705.08408 says the following action
\begin{align}
L = \pi_\phi \dot{\phi} + \pi_f \dot{f} - (\pi_\phi^2 + \pi_f e^\phi)\tag{2.1}
\end{align}
reduces to a Schwarzian action $L = \{f,\tau\}$. dot means $\tau$ derivative. They says we can show this by

Enforcing the constraint $\dot{f} = e^\phi$ since the quantity $\pi_f$ is a Lagrange multiplier.

Integrating $\pi_\phi$.


However, I can't prove this claim. The constraint becomes $$\phi = \log \dot{f} \to\ \dot{\phi}=\frac{\ddot{f}}{\dot{f}}. $$ Therefore
\begin{align}
L = \pi_\phi \left( \frac{\ddot{f}}{\dot{f}}\right)^2 - \pi_\phi^2. 
\end{align}
Performing Gaussian integral, I think this becomes
\begin{align}
L = \frac{1}{4}\left( \frac{\ddot{f}}{\dot{f}}\right)^2.
\end{align}
Therfore this is not Schwarzian action, since the difference cannot be written in terms of total derivatives. What am I missing?

If you add the total derivative $-\frac{1}{2}\frac{d}{d \tau} \left(\frac{f''}{f'}\right)$, you get $-\frac{1}{2}\left(\frac{f'''}{f'}-\frac{3}{2}\left(\frac{f''}{f'}\right)^2\right)=-\frac{1}{2}\{f,\tau\}$. Lagrangians scaled by an overall constant are equivalent, so this Lagrangian is equivalent to the Schwarzian action.

TL;DR: Ref. 1 seems to be cavalier about the overall multiplicative normalization of the Lagrangian.

For starters, it would have been natural to include a half in the term $\pi_\phi^2\leadsto\frac{1}{2}\pi_\phi^2$ of the Hamiltonian Lagrangian (2.1) to achieve a conventional normalization of the kinetic term $\frac{1}{4}\dot{\phi}^2\leadsto\frac{1}{2}\dot{\phi}^2$ in the Lagrangian in Fig. 1 on the very next page. [This is effectively an inverse Legendre transformation from Hamiltonian to Lagrangian formalism.]
When we then integrate out the Lagrange multiplier $\pi_f$, the reduced Lagrangian becomes $L = \frac{1}{4}\left( \frac{\ddot{f}}{\dot{f}}\right)^2\leadsto\frac{1}{2}\left( \frac{\ddot{f}}{\dot{f}}\right)^2$, which up to a total derivative is $L=-\frac{1}{2}\{f,\tau\}\leadsto-\{f,\tau\}$, i.e. proportional to the Schwarzian derivative. [Note that Ref. 1 incorrectly writes $L=\{f,\tau\}$ in Fig. 1, as OP has already mentioned.]

In other places [e.g. in eq. (2.10) and below eq. (1.2)] Ref. 1 seems to stick with their unconventional normalization.


References:

T.G. Mertens, G.J. Turiaci & H.L. Verlinde, Solving the Schwarzian via the Conformal Bootstrap, arXiv:1705.08408.


Notes for later: Compared the above with the inverse parameterization of Jevicki, Suzuki & Yoon https://arxiv.org/abs/1603.06246 eqs. (3.8)-(3.12).
